# Format heatmap Y values as links in AnyChart

Tags: javascript, anychart

I'm trying to add links to my heatmap to Y values and [documentation](https://docs.anychart.com/Appearance_Settings/Text_Settings#html) says that I'm only allowed to apply certain amount of html tags and none of them is `<a></a>` tag. So, is there a way to make Y values as links?

Comment: You have to set from listener follow the [Event Listeners](https://docs.anychart.com/Common_Settings/Event_Listeners), and [Javascript Events](http://6.anychart.com/products/anychart/docs/users-guide/JavaScriptEvents.html)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the current version of the library 8.8.0 doesn't support links in labels, not all tags are supported in Html labels formatting.
But you can open the required links by click on chart items. For details, check [the sample](https://playground.anychart.com/yryWbGYA). The link will be open by double click on any item. The links you can apply right in the data.